# No signature of method / Atlassian Jira / Groovy

Tags: groovy, jira

I'm trying to get DueDate and add a several days to it:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue
Date duedate = issue.getDueDate().plus(30);
MutableIssue.setDueDate(duedate.toTimestamp());
```

And then, I get the following error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue.setDueDate() is applicable for argument types: (java.sql.Timestamp) values: [2018-08-31 00:00:00.0]
at Script311.run(Script311.groovy:5)
```

I have tried different solutions, but none works. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `.setDueDate(...)` on the MutableIssue class itself; it's not a static method.  You need to call `setDueDate(...)` on an instance of the class.  Assuming `issue` is a MutableIssue instance (in your code it's not obvious where it's coming from) you should be able to just call `issue.setDueDate(duedate.toTimestamp());`